# Change Backand field type from string to float producing a valid model produces error in new schema

Tags: backand

Warning
The Model is valid.
Changes made to the model include changes to fields types.
Those changes may result in a loss or corruption of data.
Click Ok to proceed

field: vIdAux, kind: field type conflict, newType: float, oldType: string, relation: AUXAUDIobjectS
field: vIdAuxdet, kind: field type conflict, newType: float, oldType: string, relation: AUXDETALLES
field: vIdAux, kind: field type conflict, newType: float, oldType: string, relation: AUXDETALLES

Comment: I could proceed avoiding the error, by removing all object types from my Model (JSON) other than users and items, saving the model (thus loosing the few test instances I had), and after this, adding again my model object types.

Answer (score 0):

Changing fields type in Backand can be done from the JSON only.
Some changes can't be done, like from Text to float and others and you should get an error message about it, others will be OK to change. You can always access the Database directly and make the changes there.

Comment: Understood. Consistent what could be expected from attempting similar row migrations directly on RDBMS schemas. Thanks.

Comment: It may still be not aligned with the (expected? hopeful?) business goal with Backand, of lowering the barrier for FrontEnd developers to build their basic back-ends.